# Is there any reference where dvija means enlightened person?

Tags: scripture, varna, enlightenment, dvija, sadhguru-jaggi-vasudev

Came across a post recently by Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev, where he says that dvija means an enlightened person:

“**Enlightened ones have always been referred to as dwijas** or ‘twice born.’ May you obliterate the creaturehood and blossom into a Being.”

[image]

However, in most scriptural references, dvija is taken to mean one whose Upanayanam has been performed. E.g. the Manusmriti 2.169 says:

> मातुरग्रेऽधिजननं द्वितीयं मौञ्जिबन्धने ।
> तृतीयं यज्ञदीक्षायां द्विजस्य श्रुतिचोदनात् ॥ १६९ ॥
>
> According to the directions of the Revealed Word, the first birth of the twice-born man is from the mother, the second, after the girdle-tying ceremony, and the third, after sacrificial initiation.—(169)

**Question**:

I would like to know whether the term dvija as meaning enlightened one has a scriptural basis. (Rather than the three varnas for whom Upanayanam has been performed).

In case yes, then what would Dvija-bandhu mean?

---

Related:

1. [Any reason for calling people, who had undergone Upanayana samskara without realisation, as dwija?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36844/any-reason-for-calling-people-who-had-undergone-upanayana-samskara-without-real/36887#36887)
2. [What is the criteria for being a dvija? Is anyone who has undergone upanayana a dvija?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19172/what-is-the-criteria-for-being-a-dvija-is-anyone-who-has-undergone-upanayana-a/19219#19219)
3. [Is there more than one interpretation of "twice born"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32478)

Comment: maybe sadhguru is giving his own interpretation for the second birth ceremony called upanayanam, and calls it enlightened. my guruji never used this interpretation. For him dvija consistently means the twice born only.

Comment: @Draupadi yes correct. everyone uses the twice born thing only. This was something new for me.